# Can't get correct position while updating view outside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have simple PagerAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    int[] res;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int[] res) {
        this.context = context;
        this.res = res;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return res.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        ImageView res1;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item, container,
                false);
        res1 = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.res1);

        res1.setImageResource(res[position]);
        imageViewWhichIsDefinedOutsideViewPagerItem.setImageResource(res[position]);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(item);

        return item;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm setting ImageViews like this:

```
res1.setImageResource(res[position]);
imageViewWhichIsDefinedOutsideViewPagerItem.setImageResource(res[position]);
```

res1 which is inflated to ViewPager has a good resource image but imageViewWhichIsDefinedOutsideViewPagerItem has a different resource. How is that possible if I am setting res[position] for both of them? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

`instantiateItem()` is called when a page is *instantiated*, not when a page is *shown*. Pages are created before they are shown, so that the animation can be smooth as the user swipes between pages.

Do not do anything in `instantiateItem()` that affects widgets outside of that individual page.

If you want to change `imageViewWhichIsDefinedOutsideViewPagerItem` when the page changes, [set up an `OnPageChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29) and do the work there.